# how to apply parent child relation in my website thru sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

scenario is like

customer_profile

```
  parent                  child
    100                      101
    100,101                  102
    100,101,102              103
```

i have a problem i have chaining system in my asp.net website,when a record has inserted each time it's parent is selected by dropdown list, i want it'll go to various level it's parent of parent's will be concatenated thru sql. 
please tell me how to design stored procedure for this chaining.
Thanks in adv

Comment: Schema/sample data would go a long way toward making this question clearer.

Comment: i means every time when record insert it' s all grand parent add to its parent name

Comment: so child column is updated with the selected value from the dropdown list and the parent column updates with all the parent names in order?